# allocate array from file data c++

Tags: c++, file-io, malloc

Here is my code where prime.txt contains some primes: 7, 11, 13, 17, 23... :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string file= "primes.txt";

    ifstream fichier; 
    
    fichier.open(file); 
    
    int count = 0, prime;
    int *buffer = (int*) malloc(8080*sizeof(int));
    
    while ( fichier >> prime){ 
        buffer[count] = prime; 
        count++; 
        
    }
    
    fichier.close();
    

  return 0;
}
```

I would like to know if there's a way to allocate an array from file's data without using loops? I saw that you can do it with binary files but I was wondering if we could do it for files with string or int too.

Comment: Do you really need to use malloc() in a `c++` program? I assume you are not permitted to use a `std::vector`

Comment: yes cause i want to use ippmalloc with it

Comment: Your code then looks fine except for the lack of a free. In a modern `c++` program we would use `std::vector<int>` and steer very clear of the manual memory management or reading the file 2 times.

Comment: If you want to do something several times then you use a loop. Can you explain what you wish the code would look like?

Comment: It only works for binary files because (in general) with binary files you are dealing with records of a fixed size. So you just divide the size of the file by the size of the record. The same technique will work just as well for text files **provided** all your prime numbers are stored in the same number of characters. That seems unlikely to be the case though, so I think you will have to use a loop.

Comment: The changed code is now broken if the number of primes is greater than 8080.

Comment: ok thank you, for larger files it might not be the best

Comment: There are multiple data items in your file.  The solution to do this without loops is to repeat the read statement many times.  If you use block reading, be aware that it has internal loops as well.  In general, loops are used to process many items or perform tasks many times (takes up less code space than repeating statements).

Comment: Search the internet for "memory mapped files".  This technique involves the OS loading the file contents into memory so you can treat the file as memory.  However, loops are still involved.

Comment: One of the fundamental issues is that you need to convert the file contents into internal format.  For example, converting "3.14159" into internal (binary) representation.  Because of this, you can't use binary format (which is a mirror image from memory).  If you have a binary file (image from memory), there would still be loops involved in transferring the data from the file to memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid *writing* the loop if you use iterators or ranges. Here is an equivalent example using ranges:

```
auto view = std::ranges::istream_view<int>(fichier);
auto copy_result = std::ranges::copy(view, buffer);
int count = std::distance(buffer, copy_result.out);
```

The loops are still there, inside the standard library. There's no way to avoid that with input streams.

> I saw that you can do it with binary files but I was wondering if we could do it for files with string or int too.

You transform the character strings into integers. Memory mapping doesn't work when the data needs to be transformed. This could work if the integers were written in binary format rather than text. That does however have the caveat that the file would not be portable to other systems that represent integers differently in memory.

Furthermore, there is no standard way to memory map files in C++. You would need to rely on an API provided by the system.

Even then, there would be loops. But those loops would be inside the operating system kernel and not having system calls in loop iterations of user code may potentially improve performance depending on usage pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that doesn't use an explicit loop:

```
fichier >> buffer[count++];  // Read and convert to internal format
fichier >> buffer[count++];  
fichier >> buffer[count++];
// Repeat for each number in the file
fichier >> buffer[count++];
```

In the runtime library, a loop is used when reading characters to build the number.  Also, the input stream may be buffered, which is another loop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are mentioning the loop used to store the length in `count` than no, you'll always need to iterate through the content of the file.

It's possible that there are some methods to do this without a explicit loop but internally they will necessarily contain a loop.